# How to test if a key doesn't exist in a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, key, nsdictionary

I tried that but event if the value is nil, it doesn't act correctly (the key "CODE_REQUEST1 doesn't exist).

```
form.souhait1_1 = contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"] != nil ? String(formatIntToString(contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"])) : ""
```

[image]

Comment: What about `@inline(__always) func index(forKey key: Dictionary.Key) -> Dictionary<Key, Value>.Index?`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question – what exactly are you trying to achieve and what problem are you encountering? As always, a [mcve] would be much appreciated.

Comment: I just would like to test if the key is existing in the dictionary contactDetails. The problem is that the value is nil as you can see in the image (expression contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"] = nil) so I know it is really nil, but when I use the expression if contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"] != nil, it execute the first argument, and it shouldn't, as it is nil...

Comment: Option-click on `contactDetails`.  What is the type?

Comment: It is : NativeDictionaryStorageOwner<String, AnyObject>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) method of `Optional` to conditionally use the (possibly existing key:s) value for a given key in your dictionary:

```
form.souhait1_1 = contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"]
    .map { String(formatIntToString($0)) } ?? "N/A"
```

If the key doesn't exist, the call to `contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"]` will be `nil`, and the `.map` call will return `nil`, in which case the `nil` coalescing operator `??` will be used to supply a default value (`"N/A"` above).

Comment: This is probably what OP wants, although the fact the LLDB is saying that `contactDetails["CODE_REQUEST1"]` resolves to an `AnyObject?!` makes me think the actual problem is around double wrapped optionals.

Comment: @Hamish yes quite much confusion in this question (but alas, any question where `Optional`'s map can be of use is too tempting for me!), but I choose to think the LLDB was simply pissed at the `AnyObject` value type of the dict ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ?? for swift3

```
var dic = ["CODE_REQUEST1":"success"]
var value = dic["CODE_REQUEST1"] ?? "" // value = success
dic = ["qq":"fail"]
value = dic["CODE_REQUEST1"] ?? "" // value = ""
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is for Swift 2 for now. I have to migrate it in the next month.

Comment: The `??` operator has been around since the days of Swift 1.

Comment: :) I didn't know, sorry.

Comment: yea, it wasn't working as it should before swift3 maybe 2